# MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR not found

Tags: compiler-errors, include

sorry to be such a newb, but I'm building a mySQL driver from source, and it needs to include mysql.h, but the compiler reports an error. The includes in FindMYSQL.cmake seem ok, so I'm guessing that CMake is missing the most basic pointer from its CMake Settings. I've tried a couple of paths in the json but no luck - I don't really know what I'm trying to point it to? I'm struggling to come to terms with c++ at the moment, so any assistance appreciated.

```
    CMake Error at cmake/FindMySQL.cmake:548 (message):
      Could not find "mysql.h" from searching "/usr/include/mysql
      /usr/local/include/mysql /opt/mysql/mysql/include
      /opt/mysql/mysql/include/mysql /usr/local/mysql/include
      /usr/local/mysql/include/mysql C:\Program Files (x86)/MySQL/*/include
      C:/MySQL/*/include"       C:\Users\Studio\Source\Repos\mysql-connector-odbc\cmake/FindMySQL.cmake 548
```

Line 548 is the fatal error message, source here:

```
    # No specific paths, try some common install paths
    find_path(MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR mysql.h ${_include_fallback_path})

    if(NOT MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find \"mysql.h\" from searching "
                        "\"${_pp_include_fallback_path}\"")
    endif()
```

If I peek at MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR:
Line 512 in FindMySQL.cmake

```
    set(MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR "${MYSQL_DIR}/include/mysql-8.0")
      if(NOT EXISTS "${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR}/include/mysql-8.0/mysql.h")
         message(FATAL_ERROR "MYSQL_DIR given, but no \"mysql.h\" "
                        "in \"${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR}\"")
      endif()
```

And the CMakeSettings.json shows:
[image: CMakeSettings.json]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate the problem and fix it by installing MySQL Server, which added the missing include paths and environmental arguments. However, to fix this problem specifically:

1. Remove the *“/mysql-8.0“* from your defined path.
2. Call **CMake** with the following *-D* option:

   cmake -DMYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR=‘C:\Program Files\MySql\mysql server 8.0\include‘

The -D command line option defines a CMake constant with a given value if needed.

3. You should then generate the cache again...
   [image]
4. Once cache generation is completed, you should see the "build all" option which indicates there aren't any missing include files / paths.
   [image]